# NSUserDefaults. Retrieving incorrect values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am saving few dictionaries in `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"event_states"] == nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"923381DC-3DCB-46CA-A6CF-C58A7AF33B89",@"guid", 
                              @"В планах",@"name", //this string will returned corrupted
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:12632256],@"color",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"isclosed",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"isfinish",

                  nil];
// and few more dictionaries same way
        ....

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[dict0,dict1,dict2,dict3] forKey:@"event_states"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    NSArray *event_states = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"event_states"];
```

When I am retrieving this data I am logging it and have a strange behavior. In some cases I am retrieving a correct value as this:

```
name = "\U0412 \U043f\U043b\U0430\U043d\U0430\U0445"
```

but in some cases as this:

```
name = "\U0412\U044b\U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U0435\U043d(\U043e)
```

and this last part in parenthesis is an extra symbol and I can't understand why it appears and what is dependence on when it appears and when it's not. What can be wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to convert your unicode to readable string and paste it in google translate

```
\U0412 \U043f\U043b\U0430\U043d\U0430\U0445 => В планах => The plans
\U0412\U044b\U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U0435\U043d(\U043e) => Выполнен(о) => Complete ?
```

So I think this happened because your code not the API.

Comment: Also you translated words right, but somehow this (o) symbol appears in the end of Complete.

Comment: You was right, I was retrieved data in this form from server.